# What is exactly RXJava and what it is used for?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

Hell everyone , I have read some articles on the internet about RxJava in Order to have a better understanding of what it is but i'm still finding it pretty hard to understand .COuld anyone advice me :
1- What is RXJava ?
2- Why do we use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an implementation of a spécification called ReactiveX, mainly it's an API for asynchronous programming with observable streams, which is based on the Observable design pattern. the most famous implementation is rxjs which is used in Angular.

You can check out the website www.reactivex.io to understand more.

> ReactiveX is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs by using observable sequences. It extends the observer pattern to support sequences of data and/or events and adds operators that allow you to compose sequences together declaratively while abstracting away concerns about things like low-level threading, synchronization, thread-safety, concurrent data structures, and non-blocking I/O.